# What is the difference between "I'm sure", "I think", "I believe"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I know these sentences are used to express opinions.
"I'm sure", "I think", "I believe"

But I don't know the exact difference between them.
What I know is that "I'm sure", "I believe" are more confidence expressions than "I think". Actually, I don't know if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that I believe is more confident than I think. By the way, I am not sure there is an accepted answer. But I will share my thoughts.

1. Being sure is to know. So this means the person has no doubt about something. Out of what you wrote, this is the most confident.
2. To think means that the person arrived at a conclusion based upon their own analytical process. This can be very good. I would take Einstein's thinking over many people's 'beliefs'. But maybe the person has horrible logic skills. Then their *thoughts* might not be reasonable.
3. To believe.... this is where it gets tricky. Beliefs can be like opinions, or preferences. Many people apparently believe in things they know are not true. Maybe they don't admit it to themselves or whatever. Maybe it is tradition to *believe* something. But to believe does not necessary rely on thought, process, or any methodology. But it is what a person *believes*. So for me, I would give beliefs the least amount of credence.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that in practice, 'I'm sure' can be used in at least two ways: 1. literally: "are you sure about that?", "yes I'm sure." meaning there is no doubt, and 2. to express hope/belief, but without certainty: "is she going to be ok?", "I'm sure she'll be fine." where the thing hasn't happened yet so no one can literally be "sure".